# List not getting displayed using AnguarJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am using `AngularJS` for data binding in my `ASP.NET MVC` website. On my View I have angular controller as given below:

```
<script>        
    function questionController($scope, $http, questions) {     
        $scope.queList = $http.get('Question/GetAllQuestions');
        $scope.testList = ['a','b'];
    }
    var queApp = angular.module("queApp", []);
    queApp.controller("queCtrl", questionController);
<script>
```

I am displaying the data as given below:

```
<div ng-app="queApp">
    <div ng-controller="queCtrl">
        {{queList}}
        {{testList}}
        <div ng-repeat="question in queList">
            {{question.Body}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code of action method is given below:

```
public JsonResult GetAllQuestions()
{
    Questions questions;
    QuestionProvider quePro = new QuestionProvider();
    questions = quePro.GetQuestions();
    return Json(questions);
}
```

I have debugged MVC controller code and found out that request is hitting the action method and a list of questions is getting returned but 
on the view I do not see that list. However a `testList` gets displayed. Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: $http.get returns a promise

Answer (score 1):

Do like this,

```
   $http.get('Question/GetAllQuestions').then(function (response){
                 $scope.queList = response.data;
                console.log(data)
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

`JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` inside controller action method made it work as given below:

```
return Json(questions, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```